# android app using a mapping service published on MY OWN PC as an ArcGIS Server IssueS

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-android

I'm developing an Android ArcGIS App using the latest esri android sdk , I need to make my app get the map I want to show which is stored in an ArcGIS server that I PHYSICALLY posses; I can't store anything on the arcgis online site, Ican't use portals as well,
the esri video lecture about publishing services talked about my case about 2 minutes of the lecture whose duration is more than an hour
what I got is
it's called enterprise architecture when you have access to all the infrastructure and is independent from the internet.

changing the way I'm working is not an option so please don't tell me to do so cause I can't

I'm using ArcGIS Server 10.0
in this page:
System requirements for 10.2.3—ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android | ArcGIS for Developers
in the last pargraph something is said about apps connecting to a  data server offline
is that my issue here?

Am I obliged to use ArcGIS server 10.2 or later?

I'm trying to use Mapping service 
if not:
every time my app tries to inilize the mapview using the url of the service I've published connection is to be refused

I seek any page to read or anything.

---

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {

MapView mMapView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 // Retrieve the map and initial extent from XML layout
//  mMapView = new MapView(this);
    mMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
 // Add dynamic layer to MapView
    mMapView.setEsriLogoVisible(true);
    mMapView.addLayer(new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("" +
    "http://10.0.2.2:8080/syriaBD10/MapServer/MobileServer"));

}
```

---

LOG:

---

```
08-07 20:59:20.469: D/ActivityThread(11276): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
08-07 20:59:20.469: D/ActivityThread(11276): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
08-07 20:59:20.469: D/ActivityThread(11276): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
08-07 20:59:20.649: D/dalvikvm(11276): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.esri.arcgis.helloworld/lib/libruntimecore_java.so 0x41943b50
08-07 20:59:20.899: D/dalvikvm(11276): Added shared lib /data/data/com.esri.arcgis.helloworld/lib/libruntimecore_java.so 0x41943b50
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276): url =http://10.0.2.2:8080/syriaBD10/MapServer/MobileServer
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2:8080 refused
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at com.esri.core.internal.io.handler.h.a(Unknown Source)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at com.esri.core.internal.io.handler.h.a(Unknown Source)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at com.esri.core.internal.tasks.ags.s.a(Unknown Source)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at com.esri.android.map.ags.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer.initLayer(Unknown Source)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at com.esri.android.map.ags.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer$1.run(Unknown Source)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080) after 1200000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:832)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    ... 18 more
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:144)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
08-07 20:59:21.109: E/ArcGIS(11276):    ... 23 more
08-07 20:59:21.199: D/libEGL(11276): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
08-07 20:59:21.209: D/libEGL(11276): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
08-07 20:59:21.219: D/libEGL(11276): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
08-07 20:59:21.219: I/Adreno200-EGL(11276): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.1_RB1.04.01.01.45.000_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3.1_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
08-07 20:59:21.219: I/Adreno200-EGL(11276): Build Date: 01/11/13 Fri
08-07 20:59:21.219: I/Adreno200-EGL(11276): Local Branch: 
08-07 20:59:21.219: I/Adreno200-EGL(11276): Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_2.0.3.1
08-07 20:59:21.219: I/Adreno200-EGL(11276): Local Patches: NONE
08-07 20:59:21.219: I/Adreno200-EGL(11276): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
08-07 20:59:21.259: D/OpenGLRenderer(11276): Enabling debug mode 0
```

---

[image]

Comment: Can you supply a link to the page/document that you are referencing?

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/system-requirements.htm

Comment: Can you supply some code and the log referencing your connection being refused?  The system requirements state v10.0+ to connect to service, which is seems you are trying to  do.  If you want to export your service to an offline data type you will need v10.2.2+ or use the Android API.

Comment: I've edited the question would you take a look

Comment: offline here meaning what exactly?
I want a service published by my pc as an arcgis server 10.0 
and an android device who are on the same wifi network to connect successfully.